# Cant get correct result from XmlDocument Load-method because of the characters

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, xmldocument

EDIT: This was solved by changing how the webservice interprates GET-requests (to UTF-8).

I send a string to an URL that returns an XML to me. But the resulting XML is not correct if I send special characters, such as å, ä, ö. And I cant get it to work.

```cs
 string name= "abc def åäö";
//name= Uri.EscapeUriString(address); - i also tried this but it messes up the åäö chars in the resulting xml
string uri = "http://blablabla&address=" + name+ "&outputFormat=xml";

System.Xml.XmlDocument x = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
x.Load(uri);
XmlElement root = x.DocumentElement;
foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
{
     XmlAttribute attr = (XmlAttribute)node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(attr.Value);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the same document in a web browser to see if you get the same document?

Comment: If I just load the same URL in the browser with the same chars I get the correct result.

Comment: The problem has nothing at all to do with `XmlDocument`. Try downloading the document by using `WebClient`. You first have to figure out how to get the other side to respond correctly before you can worry about loading the correct response into an `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Im using CF so I tried HttpWebRequest instead of WebClient, but it seems to send the hex code to the other side just like the Load method. Is there something else I can try to get the correct response?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are doing is correct. You should end up with the characters encoded as pairs of hex digits, each preceded by a percentage symbol, e.g. `å` becomes `%c3%a5`. The web server/application server should transparently decode these back to the corresponding characters.

Also see [HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencodeunicode.aspx), which will uses an alternative encoding, although I'm not sure that this will be handled by all web servers.

Comment: Thats correct, the problem is that I get results based on those pairs of hex digits, so they dont seem to be decoded back on the other side. Isnt there a way to call Load without them being "translated"?

Comment: in this case, i suppose the server application is simply not correctly decoding the url parameter and your code is absolutely fine. Your browser showns the correct values when you do not encode them by simple coincidence that the url parameters are "correctly" encoded for the resulting document.

Comment: Is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps, but remember that attr.Value is going to escape Xml-type escaping. That doesn't **seem** like it could be the problem, though. Instead of checking attr.Value, check node.OuterXml to see if that matches your expectations.

Comment: Im getting a result, but its not the correct one. If I change the string to something valid then the outcome will be right. So that shouldnt be it. (I also checked inside the XML using a breakpoint).

Comment: What happens when you browse to the url. Does that give expected results?

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you have done that. What I would do is save the browsed file, then load it, and do some reads and writes programmatically using the attr.value, figure out if that behaves uniformly.

Comment: Yes, but how do I browse to a file that shows the correct result from the code (i.e a file that looks like I wouldve typed the URL in my browser)? See my respons to John Saunders aswell.

Comment: My goal was to try to narrow down what is happening, if there is strangeness due to accessing the xml via url. So the idea was to use the browser to go to the url, save what you see in the browser (which you said appeared correctly) then load that file into XmlDocument and then see if your attr.val is the same (bad), and/or do some reads of attr.val and write the attr.val to another node, then check to see if things are uniform.

Comment: Oh OK, if I save the correct document and then read it I get correct results, using the same code (except for the document path ofcourse).

Comment: If OuterXml of the url accessed data is equal to the downloaded file, then the workaround is obvious. But I suspect that isnt the case somehow. I would go snooping around in XmlDocument, and see if there is some type of setting that might be the culprit. Also look into the suggestion of using WebClient class above.